# ReactJS: How to pass multiple values in value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, autocomplete

I want to pass multiple values under value in react class component. Like in `value={this.state.port1, this.state.port2, .....etc }`

Is there any way?

```js
return (
  <ReactAutocomplete
    items={this.state.searchData}
    shouldItemRender={(item, value) =>
      item.NameWoDiacritics.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1
    }
    getItemValue={(item) => item.Name}
    renderItem={(item, highlighted) => (
      <div
        key={item.id}
        style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? "#eee" : "white" }}
      >
        {item.Name}
      </div>
    )}
    value={(this.state.Port1, this.state.Port2)}
    onChange={(e) => this.childOnChange(e)}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an object

`value={{port1: this.state.Port1, port2: this.state.Port2}}`

Comment: Can you explain it further??

Comment: have you got it?

Comment: Yes...although my solution was different in this scenario... but this is also correct

Comment: Yes...although my solution was different in this scenario... but this is also correct

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it like an "object".

```
value={{ this.state.Port1, this.state.Port2}}
```

or

```
value={{ value1: this.state.Port1, value2: this.state.Port2 }}
```

Comment: So try pass like a "object"
(I've edited the anwser)

Comment: how should i define this value1, value2.... its showing error as:TypeError: value.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: It occurred because you are not treating the data as an array in the function shouldItemRender()